# Exclude low quality questions in relevance tab, or sort the questions by votes/views

Tags: feature-request, low-quality-posts, search, sorting

When someone clicks on the Relevance tab, it's showing low quality questions in the top, which is not good.

e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=java+multithreading+is%3AQ and https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=log4shell

*First posts in both these (important) searches do have a negative score of -5!*

Since Relevance is the first tab shown to the user, it would be great if the questions are also sorted by some quality metric, like votes or views.

Any thoughts in this regard?

Comment: No. Relevance tab should show good questions. If it does not serve our purpose, it can be removed.

Comment: I would vote against sorting the "relevance" tab differently, because after all, its sole purpose is to be sorted according to how close the question matches your query. And people also need to be able to specifically search for low quality posts, as part of directed cleanup efforts. Experienced users can use `score:0.` to exclude downvoted posts, and use the "votes" tab to sort by votes. However, I can see how the default search behaviour could be rather unhelpful for inexperienced users... maybe have a personal "default" tab option that gets initialised to "votes"?

Answer (score 6):

Whether or not a question is "relevant" has very little to do with its quality or perceived quality, based on votes. What makes a question "relevant" is how well it matches the query. Also, the question being "low quality" does not mean that it doesn't potentially have great answers, which would indeed be extremely relevant if you're looking for a solution to a similar question.

I could perhaps see vote count being a secondary sort, though, such that when two or more questions are equally relevant to the query, the one(s) with more votes would be displayed first. Anything more than that, though, would no longer be a "relevance" sort.

Answer (score 3):

TL;DR

- we can't assume "Relevance to Search Engines" is the same as "Relevance of a Post to Users"
- To stay like today, "Relevance" should be reworded to **"Match"**
- A default sorting should also **account for quality** to provide a better UX

---

**Relevance as the default sorting is totally misleading, if not incorporating some "quality" metrics.** People expect to see useful posts at the top - but there are so many cases today's "Relevance" is directing users to useless posts.

Another example: see https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=log4shell where the first post has been closed, given it wasn't even fulfilling Stack Overflow's own *quality guidelines*!

Even worse, any "crappy-content but perfectly-worded post" is forever "unbeatable" given quality is quite independent of relevance/wording -- the only way to move down bad posts is to rename/manipulate them with typos and other bad wording.

---

Some **quality measure** should be added, and I'd point at least to the following

- closed / not
- number of downvotes / balance

So, a way better default sorting could be "Better Relevance", combining "Match" and "Quality".